# WWW Subdomain isn't working on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications

I can get to my GAE project by navigating to http://SonnyBrooksStudios.com but I cannot get there by navigating to http://www.SonnyBrooksStudios.com. I bought my domain through Godaddy. Did I set something up incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a resource record for the SonnyBrooksStudios.com domain using values as shown:

Type: CNAME

Alias: www

Canonical name: ghs.googlehosted.com

Go to GoDaddy.com and go to Domain details-> DNS Zone file

Create a new record of type CNAME(Alias) with following values:

Host: www

Points to: ghs.googlehosted.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have the DNS setup wrong for the www subdomain. You want add a new subdomain in the app engine console under settings for the www subdomain. Then it will instruct you to add www.sonnybrooksstudios.com as a CNAME record pointing to ghs.googlehosted.com, which you will need to do with your registrar.